# Plesk Obsidian - Subir archivos al servidor

Tags: base-de-datos, fileupload, plesk, almacenamiento

¡Saludos! Estoy trabajando en una base de datos en un sitio web para una pequeña empresa y no estoy acostumbrado a usar Plesk así que estoy atascado en un problema.

Primero que todo, tanto el servidor Plesk como el dominio de dicha página fueron comprados por la empresa, por lo que yo solo tuve que subir la base de datos. En la base de datos se requiere subir documentos al servidor desde el sitio web,  (cosas como facturas, memos y eso) pues muchas de estas cargas serán realizadas por secretarias que no podrán acceder al sitio de Plesk.

La cuestión es que he intentado poner la carpeta donde van destinado los archivos en varias secciones del plesk (httdocs, compartición de archivos, etc.) y en ninguna me permite subir documentos, incluso intente subirla a la sección de archivos compartidos en los documentos públicos y nada (luego leí que solo el administrador y usuarios de Plesk pueden hacerlo, pero yo necesito que se suba desde la página web).

No sé si tenga que realizar alguna configuración especifica para ello, crear una carpeta en un lugar especifico o sencillamente usar otro servició externo. La verdad agradecería mucho su ayuda.

¡De antemano agradezco el tiempo que se tomaron para leer mi inquietud!

Answer (score -1):

imagino que ya lo tendrás solucionado pero es sencillo, solo necesitas crear una suscripcción para que se pueda accedes a archivos, base de datos y correo, tambien puedes crear una cuenta de FTP adicional y especificar la ruta root de ese usuario que puede ser separa de httpdocs y dentro de esa carpeta donde no verian mas ficheros. si lo que quieres es subirlos por php solo tienes que crear un script que se encargue de eso, cualquier duda contesta especificando un poco mas y te ayudaré, un saludo

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]